# Is it possible to create an HDF5 virtual dataset (VDS) using collective I/O?

Tags: hdf5, hdf

I am trying to link four different hdf5 files into a single virtual dataset (VDS) collectively. By saying collectively, I mean every process calls H5Pset_virtual(...) for its own local file. Is it possible to create VDS files in this way? I have searched lots of VDS tutorials and documentations (like [this](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/docNewFeatures/NewFeaturesVirtualDatasetDocs.html) or [this](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/vds.html)) by HDF5 group, but cannot find such a feature or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the current version of HDF5 (1.10.1) there is no communication of metadata information between processes. So, if you want to use VDS, one process should be responsible for creating the VDS file.

Comment: Is it still true for 1.12?

Comment: No, I think it is supported now in 1.12.

Comment: Actually I could not find any way to make it work. There isn't even a property to set the dataset creation collective, because this is usually done at write time, not dataset creation time. It turns out VDS are only created, not written.